# Tail Recursions in erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang, tail-recursion, tail

I'm learning Erlang from the very basic and have a problem with a tail recursive function. I want my function to receive a list and return a new list where element = element + 1. For example, if I send [1,2,3,4,5] as an argument, it must return [2,3,4,5,6]. The problem is that when I send that exact arguments, it returns [[[[[[]|2]|3]|4]|5]|6].

My code is this:

```
-module(test).
-export([test/0]).

test()->
  List = [1,2,3,4,5],
  sum_list_2(List).

sum_list_2(List)->
  sum_list_2(List,[]).

sum_list_2([Head|Tail], Result)->
  sum_list_2(Tail,[Result|Head +1]);
sum_list_2([], Result)->
  Result.
```

However, if I change my function to this:

```
sum_list_2([Head|Tail], Result)->
  sum_list_2(Tail,[Head +1|Result]);
sum_list_2([], Result)->
  Result.
```

It outputs [6,5,4,3,2] which is OK. Why the function doesn't work the other way around([Result|Head+1] outputing [2,3,4,5,6])?

PS: I know this particular problem is solved with list comprehensions, but I want to do it with recursion.

Comment: It's very common in Erlang to simply `lists:reverse/1` the list after operating on it exactly to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, but it doesn't seem very optimal. With short lists, there will be no problem though.

Comment: See http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion for a good guide on tail recursion in Erlang.  It actually claims the opposite - that the built-in `lists:reverse/1` function will provide more benefit on longer lists.

Comment: I'm actually learning Erlang with that guide, but I can't find the actual solution for my problem. I guess I'll have to read more about it. Thanks

Comment: Also, take a look at http://ferd.ca/erlang-s-tail-recursion-is-not-a-silver-bullet.html for some information on body vs tail recursion.  For this particular problem, I benchmarked a body vs tail recursion (plus list reversal) and the two are essentially neck and neck.  Using ++, as suggested in one of the answers, is vastly slower.  In one quick test of 10000 elements, it took 1000× longer to run.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of manipulation you should use list comprehension:

```
1> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6].
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
2> [X+1 || X <- L].
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

it is the fastest and most idiomatic way to do it.

A remark on your fist version: `[Result|Head +1]` builds an improper list. the construction is always `[Head|Tail]` where Tail is a list. You could use `Result ++ [Head+1]` but this would perform a copy of the Result list at each recursive call.

You can also look at the code of `lists:map/2` which is not tail recursive, but it seems that actual optimization of the compiler work well in this case:

```
inc([H|T]) -> [H+1|inc(T)];
inc([]) -> [].
```

**[edit]**

The internal and hidden representation of a list looks like a chained list. Each element contains a term and a reference to the tail. So adding an element on top of the head does not need to modify the existing list, but adding something at the end needs to mutate the last element (the reference to the empty list is replaced by a reference to the new sublist). As variables are not mutable, it needs to make a modified copy of the last element  which in turn needs to mutate the previous element of the list and so on. As far as I know, the optimizations of the compiler do not  make the decision to mutate variable (deduction from the the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html)).

Comment: can you elaborate on your note about "this would perform a copy of the Result list at each recursive call"?   I would have expected that the compiler would optimise that array and effectively just append the new element to the original list.

Answer (score -1):

The function that produces the result in reverse order is a natural consequence of you adding the newly incremented element to the *front* of the `Result` list.  This isn't uncommon, and the recommended "fix" is to simply `list:reverse/1` the output before returning it.

Whilst in this case you could simply use the `++` operator instead of the `[H|T]` "cons" operator to join your results the other way around, giving you the desired output in the correct order:

```
sum_list_2([Head|Tail], Result)->
  sum_list_2(Tail, Result ++ [Head + 1]);
```

doing so isn't recommended because the `++` operator [always copies](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#id57646) it's (increasingly large) left hand operand, causing the algorithm to operate in O(n^2) time instead of the `[Head + 1 | Tail]` version's O(n) time.

Comment: This function has `O(N^2)` time complexity.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil thanks - I've looked into this and you're correct, so I've updated my answer accordingly.